# Keep getting "(lldb)" and Why unwrap element after using .indexOf()

Tags: swift, lldb

I am making a program in the Swift programming language. I am very new at the language as well :).
My command-line program is supposed to switch the lowest value in the array with the first element in the array.

For example,
Input = [1, 7, 100, -4, 800, 9999]; Output = [-4, 7, 100, 1, 800, 9999]

This is the unfinished code. I get a breakpoint and (lldb) pops up. I

```
import Foundation

var mainArray : Array<Int> = [1, 7, 100, -4, 800, 9999]

var lowestNumber = mainArray[0]

for element in mainArray{
    if element < lowestNumber {
        lowestNumber = element
    }
}

let lowestIndex = mainArray.indexOf(lowestNumber)
print(lowestIndex!)
let firstNumber = mainArray[0]
let firstIndex = mainArray.indexOf(firstNumber)
```

I get a breakpoint when I declare lowestIndex and it prints (lldb). Also, xCode wants me to put an "!" to unwrap the value, why do I have to if I know it is an integer?

Comment: You can get the `lowestNumber` by just using: `let lowestNumber = mainArray.min()!`

Comment: Yeah, I knew that... But it was weird since it was wrapped. Also, I am trying to mimic a Java project I made during the year and I wanted to make it as similar as possible. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(lldb)` is the command prompt when you pause the program to debug. From there, you can type commands to examine the state of your program. For example, to print the content of `mainArray`:

```
(lldd) po mainArray
```

`mainArray.indexOf(aNumber)` returns an `Optional<Int>` because the number may not be found in the array, in which case it returns `nil`.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it!